# How to Submit a form with Two HTML button without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript

I am newbie on programming and now I am facing an issue. I have a form which has two HTML buttons, both buttons are SUBMIT TYPE and both executes the same Python function (using IF and ELIF loops to determinate tasks each buttons has to execute).

I want to know if is it possible to execute the first Button BUT without reloading the page and at the same time it will be able to execute its task on server side?

The second button is a normal button ( I want to say when I click the second button It can be able to reload the page and execute tasks it should execute on server side)

I already have used `event.preventDefault();`, but when I use this, the page can't be reloaded BUT it doesn't execute my function on server side. I think I need some Ajax code, but I have never used it, so I would like some idea.

HTML:

```
<form action="/carga/cerrar" method="POST">
 <div class="row center">
  <div class="col l3 m3 offset-l3 offset-m3 s6">
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="Save" id="Save">Save
      <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col l3 m3 s6">
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="Close" id="Close">Close
      <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>



document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function(event){ 
  event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/carga/cerrar",
        type:"POST",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("error");
        }
    })
  alert("Guardado----");
  });

document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", function(event){ 
  location.reload();
 alert("Closed----");
});
```

Comment: You  should look into ajax

Comment: `formElement.onsubmit = e=>{ e.preventDefault(); }`

Comment: I am newbie using this tools, so I have never used ajax before,... but I now already have added some code what I have been trying, but nothing is working.... I would like some example with my code.. Thank you..

Comment: You don’t have to use the html form element. Instead give each html input element an Id tag. Add an onclick method to your button. The method can read the data from the html elements with document.getElementById calls to get the values. Then use a fetch command to send data to the server. It can all be done with pure JavaScript.

Comment: Your code looks ok. Check you server if it's sending the correct data. You can use Postwoman or Postman for that. If everything works fine with the tools and server side go on and create your scripts.
Also, you can check this guides for some more infos about fetch API:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data

Comment: Also a nice tool for VSCode a good Alternative for Postwoman.io:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client